# Bash concatenate array entries without spaces in between

Tags: arrays, bash, performance, concatenation

**Problem**

I'm writing an bash script (version 4.3.48). There I have an array and want to concatenate all entries as a single string. The following code do such task (but lag in some case):

```
declare -a array=(one two three)
echo "${array[@]}"
```

Unfortunately I get this output, including spaces in between the array entries:

```
one two three
```

But what I actually need is this:

```
onetwothree
```

---

**Background**

I try to avoid using a for-loop and concatenate it on my own, cause I call this very often (more than each second) and I guess such a loop is much more expensive than use a build-in function.

So any suggestions how to obtain the required result?

Comment: Did you mean `declare -a array=(one two three)`?

Comment: @rici ty, i edited it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`printf` gives you a lot more control over formatting, and it is also a bash builtin:

```
printf %s "${array[@]}" $'\n'
```

(That works because the shell's `printf` keeps on repeating the pattern until the arguments are all used up.)

Answer (score 7):

First, that's the wrong way to initialize an array:

```
$ declare -A array=( one two three )
bash: array: one: must use subscript when assigning associative array
bash: array: two: must use subscript when assigning associative array
bash: array: three: must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

`declare -A` is for associative arrays. Just do this

```
$ array=( one two three )
$ declare  -p array
declare -a array='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")'
```

---

You want to use the `*` subscript instead of `@`. That joins the array elements using the first character of the `IFS` array. If you don't want any separator, assign the empty string to IFS. Since lots of things depend on IFS, I typically use a subshell to contain the modifications:

```
$ (IFS=; echo "${array[*]}")
onetwothree
```

To assign the result to a variable, it's the usual command substitution syntax:

```
$ joined=$(IFS=; echo "${array[*]}"); echo "$joined"
onetwothree
```

And we can see that the IFS value in this shell (space, tab, newline) is unchanged:

```
$ printf "%s" "$IFS" | od -c
0000000      \t  \n
0000003
```

---

If performance is a goal and you want to avoid spawning a subshell, use a function:

```
$ concat_array() { local -n a=$1; local IFS=; echo "${a[*]}"; }
$ concat_array array
onetwothree
```

with bash version older than 4.3, use an indirect variable instead of a nameref

```
$ concat_array() { local tmp="${1}[*]"; local IFS=; echo "${!tmp}"; }
```

Comment: I would use the `-v` option of `printf` to define `joined`, to avoid forking a new shell for the command substitution.

Comment: D'oh. I feel like deleting my answer now.

Comment: Using ur approach lead to laggy outputs for me. Sry but the for-loop was more efficient. :/

Comment: @glennjackman no, that fine. It was interesting and i read for the difference of [@] and [*].

Answer (score 1):

No need for a subshell when removing the ";" with following ?

```
IFS="" echo "${array[*]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using for loop

```bash
declare -a array=(one two three)

for item in  "${array[@]}";do
    s+="$item"
done

echo "$s"
```